# Calling shell script from adobe livecycle workbench?

Tags: livecycle, workbench

Is there anyway to call shell script from Adobe livecycle workbench?

I tried with `executescript` service and used command `exec(scriptname)` in `beanshell`.

If there is, please provide a example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use an executeScript activity for that.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("executablecommand");
int exitValue = proc.waitFor();
```

The above script would wait for the command to finish. You can also grab the output and error streams by using the process reference.

Here is a very useful post about `Runtime.exec`. http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

If you wish to be able to do better exception handling you can still use `Runtime.exec` but create a custom java component for executing shell commands to wrap that functionality. You might even build a scripting engine component to execute groovy scripts or so.